# Issue with tree traversal, finding div ID to be used variably - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I've been trying to figure this out but I'm coming up short. Have really tried searching the best I could to come up with the answer, including jQuery API documentation and other SO posts. I feel like I'm almost there but I'm either misunderstanding something or I'm approaching this goal incorrectly.

For multiple different sections, I have 2 clickable icons in separate div's, 1 (lets say iconA) shown on load and 1 hidden (iconB) on load. When (iconA) is clicked, it hides the [sectionA] where (iconA) is located then shows the [sectionB] where (iconB) is located. I then want (iconB) to hide [sectionB] and show [sectionA].

Clearly I can't use toggle because one of the sections is always hidden at any given point. And since I'm trying to write a script that I can use for multiple sections and multiple icons, with different names, I can't just set 1-1 class names for ALL icons and sections.

I've created a jsfiddle to illustrate. Below I'll write a quick example.

HTML:

```
<div class="sectionAparent>
   <div class="sectionA" id="example>
      <i class="fa fa-code contbtn">iconA (shown on load)</i>
   </div>
</div
<div class="sectionB" id="exampleSHOW">
   <i class="fa fa-minus minushide">iconB (hidden on load)</i>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.contbtn').click(function(){
    var contid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+contid+'show').slideToggle(1000);
    $(this).hide(1000);
});
```

-this first one is to hide sectionA and show sectionB, which works fine.

```
$('.minushide').click(function(){
    var cbtn = $(this).closest('.sectionB').siblings('.sectionAparent').find('div[id]');
    var cid = $(cbtn).attr('id')
   $('#'+cid+'show').slideUp(1000);
   $(cid).slideDown(1000);
});
```

-So my thoughts were to jump up to the closest ancestor that is a sibling to the section containing the ID that I need. Then find the div with that ID, retrieve that ID, and use it show the section containing the ID and hiding the section with the ID+more. The goal is for this to be variable for multiple different sections with similar naming conventions without having to hard-code the section names in a list inside my script.

Hope this makes sense and I apologize for the wall of text, just wanted to make sure I conveyed what I'm trying to do and where I'm at. If my logic is incorrect or there is an easier way to do this, then I'm all ears! Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/dankbawls/wnjxwyfy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to append the '#' character to sid in the second last line of the js

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnjxwyfy/13/)
     `$('#'+sid).slideDown(2000);`

Comment: Use `[text](link)` to make it clickable link.

Comment: lol wow, I knew I was close but I guess it pays to take breaks :P thanks for indulging me and pointing out the obvious!

Comment: haha..we've all been down that road...a second opinion always helps..cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using class (`sectionhide`) to toggle visibility, you can look into [.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method.

It has an [overriden](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) constructor to accept 2 arguments, `className` and `state` (*a boolean value*)

Based on this `state`, it will add/remove class. `True`  means *add* and `false` means *remove*

---

```js
$('.minushide, .contbtn').on("click", function() {
  var container = $(this).closest('.container');
  var nextContainer = container.next('.container').length > 0 ? container.next('.container') : container.prev('.container');
  container.toggleClass('sectionhide', true)
  nextContainer.toggleClass('sectionhide', false)
})
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/wnjxwyfy/12/)

**Note:** I have added a common class `container` to both `div`s to have a common pattern

---

For a carousel kind of behaviour, you can use `index` to find index of element to be shown and hide all.

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/wnjxwyfy/14/)

Comment: Interesting approach. I already use 'container' class names via bootstrap but I get what you're saying. I wasn't aware of the override so I'll have to research that more. Thanks for your input!